# Is there a way to add a readme or docstring to a mongodb collection and/or database?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to describe my MongoDB databases and collections -- what data is present, its relationships to others. Basically, explain what is in the database/collection. Is there a way to do this built into MongoDB?